# MySQL group by force to return null value if does not exists in the table

Tags: mysql

hope all doing well, i do have a small problem regarding mysql, as i am not that much experienced in query so please help me to solve the below query, i have one mark table having column as per the below table, i want an output that group by exam type and return null value if there is no record in the table with group by.

```
subject       examtype     fullmark    secured
SCIENCE       CLS          50          20 
SCIENCE       CLS          50          50
MATHEMATICS   MNT          50          10
MATHEMATICS   MNT          50          35
MATHEMATICS   MNT          100         85
SCIENCE       MCK          100         89 
MATHEMATICS   CMP          100         72
ENGLISH       PST          50          33
```

my current query is as below

```
SELECT round((SUM(`secured`)/SUM(`fullmark`))*100) as percent,subject,examtype FROM tbl_marks WHERE subject = 'MATHEMATICS' GROUP BY examtype
```

the above query returns me the below result

```
    percent   subject      examtype
    72        MATHEMATICS  CMP
    65        MATHEMATICS  MNT
```

I want my output as the below

```
percent   subject      examtype
72        MATHEMATICS  CMP
65        MATHEMATICS  MNT
0         MATHEMATICS  CLS
0         MATHEMATICS  MCK
0         MATHEMATICS  PST
```

how to query it please help me, Thank you in advance.

Comment: update your question and add  the expected  result coherent with your sample  ..  (don't post image sample .. post text sample)

Comment: @scaisEdge i did update and remove the image and added my output what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query creates every combination of subject and examtypes, then uses a right outer join to pull in the combinations that aren't seen in your core query.

```
SELECT
  coalesce(round((SUM(secured)/SUM(fullmark))*100), 0) as percent,
  all_subjects_examtypes.subject,
  all_subjects_examtypes.examtype
from
  tbl_marks
  right outer join (
    select distinct
      s.subject,
      e.examtype
    from
      tbl_marks as s
      cross join tbl_marks as e
  ) as all_subjects_examtypes on
    tbl_marks.subject = all_subjects_examtypes.subject and
    tbl_marks.examtype = all_subjects_examtypes.examtype
where
  all_subjects_examtypes.subject = 'MATHEMATICS'
group by
  all_subjects_examtypes.examtype
```

Comment: Yes it gives me what i want actually, thank you a lot Mr. @Jeff Breadner Thanks again.

Comment: Hello @Jeff Breadner i do have another issue regarding your solution ll you please help me to solve this, i want to filter the data using student id but i can't get desire result when i put a condition `where sid = 20` the result set not returning the 0 value of the percent if the student not appear the examtype, how to put the condition any solution ll be appreciate.

Comment: Please see here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b5ecc/6/0  If this doesn't work, please create a new question with your table structure and desired result set and post a link to the question back here as a comment.

Comment: Yes Mr.@Jeff Breadner It works for me but ll you please tell me why the query gets too slow while  using month filter.

Comment: The `all_subjects_examtypes` subquery is probably quite large -- if you run that subquery on its own, how many rows does it return?  This result set is then (without indexes) joined back to the `tbl_marks` table.  It would be much more efficient to apply filters to this inner table, so as to reduce the number of joins made as early as possible in the query.

Comment: hello Mr.@Jeff Breadner, i am weak in this joining of tables ll you please suggest me some solution or i'll create a new question and put the link here?

Comment: I think it would be good to create a new question, which a reference to this question, example data that includes the new column(s) that aren't included here, with a new desired outcome.    If your primary concerns are applying filters efficiently then clearly state those concerns.  It's a bit much to get through as an add-on for this question, I think, and others may well propose better solutions than myself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a record in your table with those exam types SO you'll have to manufacturer a record set that does contain a record with those examtypes.

You can get that record set by cross joining distinct subjects with distinct examtypes:

```
SELECT dsubject.subject, dexamptype.examtype
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM tbl_marks) dsubject,
            (SELECT DISTINCT examptype FROM tbl_marks) dexamptype
```

Now you have a record set with every subject and every exam type for those subjects

You can use this in a query like:

```
SELECT
    round((SUM(tbl_marks.`secured`)/SUM(tbl_marks.`fullmark`))*100) as percent
    subject_examtype.subject,
    subject_examtype.examtype   
FROM
    (
        SELECT dsubject.subject, dexamptype.examtype
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM tbl_marks WHERE subject = 'MATHEMATICS') dsubject,
            (SELECT DISTINCT examptype FROM tbl_marks) dexamptype
    ) subject_examtype
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_marks 
        ON subject_examtype.subject = tbl_marks.subject
            AND subject_examptype.examtype = subject.examtype
GROUP BY subject_examtype.subject, subject_examtype.examtype;
```

Since it's just the one subject you are after, this would be the same:

```
SELECT
    round((SUM(tbl_marks.`secured`)/SUM(tbl_marks.`fullmark`))*100) as percent
    subject_examtype.subject,
    subject_examtype.examtype   
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 'MATHEMATICS' as subject, examtype FROM tbl_marks) subject_examtype
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_marks 
        ON subject_examtype.subject = tbl_marks.subject
            AND subject_examptype.examtype = subject.examtype
GROUP BY subject_examtype.subject, subject_examtype.examtype;
```

But if you want to do it for more subjects, then the first version of the query makes more sense.